# changing colorbox size wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, colorbox

Here's a [url](http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/honda-crv-2012-2/), it's a wordpress site, colorbox is built in the theme, classipress 3 and doesn't have an option to change it. If you click on any photo colorbox popup will open

```css
#colorbox {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 1028.89px;
  left: 482px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 442px;
  height: 355px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#colorbox {
  outline: 0;
}

#colorbox,
#cboxContent,
#cboxLoadedContent {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

#colorbox,
#cboxOverlay,
#cboxWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cboxOverlay {
  background: url(images/overlay.png) repeat 0 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}

#cboxOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#colorbox,
#cboxOverlay,
#cboxWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/theme-framework/js/colorbox/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/theme-framework/js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.min.js"></script>
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"></div>
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 1028.89px; left: 482px; position: absolute; width: 442px; height: 355px; opacity: 1;">
  <div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 355px; width: 442px;">
    <div>
      <div id="cboxTopLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopCenter" style="float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopRight" style="float: left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 313px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 313px;">
        <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 400px; overflow: hidden; height: 285px;"><img class="cboxPhoto" src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/584970-800x600.jpg" height="285" width="380" style="cursor: pointer; width: 380px; height: 285px; float: none;"></div>
        <div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;">IMG_9935</div>
        <div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: block;"></div><button type="button" id="cboxPrevious" style="display: block;">previous</button><button type="button" id="cboxNext" style="display: block;">next</button><button id="cboxSlideshow" style="display: none;"></button>
        <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay"
          style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
        <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div><button type="button" id="cboxClose">close</button></div>
      <div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 313px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxBottomLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div id="cboxBottomCenter" style="float: left; width: 400px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxBottomRight" style="float: left;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; max-width: none; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

The snippet is not working correctly due to an iframe error here on stackoverflow but  anyway. I changed the width and height of `#colorbox` and `#cboxWrapper` and `cboxphoto` and `cboxoverlay` nothing happened. I just want to popup to open full screen. And if possible the thumbnails below it.

Comment: Did you try using `!important` in your css?

Comment: @ovokuro yes, plus when working chrome inspector there's no need to use `!important` because if you changed the width for example it will comment out the other width so you can test the code, but yes i tried

Comment: Do you have access to the plugin css?

Comment: @ovokuro do you mean this? http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/theme-framework/js/colorbox/colorbox.css yes I can get to it or I can override what I need easily

Comment: I don't see the problem you are describing. If I open the url you provided and click on an image the popup is in full-screen. However, it removes the scroll bar and doesn't add it after you close the popup so you will have to reload the site each time.

Comment: @Aaron3219 here https://imgur.com/a/c0kkWWk you see the image of the car? I want that to open as big as the size of the browser, I tried changing the size of the image and image wrapper too 100% and 100vh and 100vw and too toooo many other things, I just couldn't get the image to be bigger

Answer (score 0):

When you intialize colorbox, you can pass following parameters to set the height and width of popup :

```
-initialWidth: "your width",
-initialHeight: "your height"
```

Checkout following js file (which you have included in minified version)
http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/theme-framework/js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js

Here all the parameters are defined with their default value.
So you can pass any of the parameters, which default value you want to change, when you initializing colorbox.

If you are unable to findout where it is initialize, you can use following code:

```
$.colorbox.remove();
$('.example').colorbox(
    {
        initialWidth: "your width",
        initialHeight: "your height",    
        'any other parameter you want to change'
    }
);
```

This will change the size of your popup.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it in 2 days and let you know, we're changing hosting now which will be done in 2 days

Comment: I changed it nothing changed, the problem is i have to change the css I guess and don't know which one, whenever I change a css it stops working